# Как связать IDataReader c XmlReader для SqlCeBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server, ado.net

Приходят XML большого объема (около 1,5 Гб), мне необходимо перенести информацию из них в таблицу БД (в моем случае SQL CE). Структура XML файла следующая (корневой тег, а в нем множество одинаковых тегов с атрибутами, количество атрибутов около 20), по сути двумерная таблица -

```
<Objects>
<Object ID="" name="" level="" />
<Object ID="" name="" level="" />
```

С XML через `XmlReader` пробую вот так:

```
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("file:////" + PathToFile);
  while (r.Read())
    {
        if ((r.Name == "Object") && (r.HasAttributes))
        {

        }
    }
```

Но как это связать дальше с `IDataREader` и `SqlCeBulkCopy` не могу понять

Библиотека находится [здесь](https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/)

UPDATE

Comment: Дай более развернутый вопрос для народа. Какую библиотеку используешь, почему надо использовать IDataReader для SqlCeBulkCopy, ссылку на предыдущий вопрос и ответ. Я то в курсе, а вот другие нет. Там пример на 30 минут писать самому писать. У меня его нет времени сейчас, а других может есть.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно реализовать `IDataReader` интерфейс, в новом классе

[тут](http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2011/12/22/using-a-custom-idatareader-to-stream-data-into-a-database/) детальная реализация для коллекции

```
public class CustomObjectDataReader : IDataReader
{
  ...
}
```

Обязательно к реализаций эти свойства и методы, остальные можно вернуть исключение

- FieldCount
- GetName
- GetOrdinal
- GetValue
- Read

Comment: все равно не могу понять)

Comment: что именно не понятно?

Comment: Как связать XmlReader и IDataReader

Comment: В вашей ссылке, они через `List` заполняют, а мне проблематично будет загрузить мою XML туда, т.к скорее всего не хватит памяти.

Comment: List не имеет значения, там можно использовать  IEnumerable, по сути вы можете прочитать xml через xmlreader, главное read метод правельно реализовать

Comment: Можете на примере показать?

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно залить весь файл, то зачем Вам IDataReader?

Используйте просто SQLXMLBULKLOADLib. Пример [**тут**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171878%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Ну а если позарез нужен IDataReader, тoгда посмотрите [**здесь**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ru-ru/7e870bd5-ebb1-4de2-a576-a4d7891159b6/load-large-nested-xml-file-into-sql-server-tables-using-custom-xmltextreader-and-sqlbulkcopy-?forum=csharpgeneral). Mожет поможет...

Comment: C SQL Server CE данная библиотека не работает, или Вы знаете способ как их подружить? Буду очень признателен